# Firebase isEmailVerified not working

Tags: angular, email, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the isEmailVerified function from firebase but im getting the error

> user.emailVerified is not a function

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  user = {} as User

  async login(user: User){
    try{
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
      .then(res => {
        //check if user has made profile if not send to profile setup page
        let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if(user.isEmailVerified()){
          console.log("Email is verified");
        }
     }catch(e){ 
       console.log(e);
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The property is `emailVerified`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#emailVerified

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User):

> emailVerified
>
> boolean
>
> True if the user's email address has been verified.

So `emailVerified` is a property, not a method (so its not callable). You could change your code like so:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  user = {} as User

  async login(user: User){
    try{
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
      .then(res => {
        //check if user has made profile if not send to profile setup page
        let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if(user.emailVerified){ // note difference on this line
          console.log("Email is verified");
        }
     }catch(e){ 
       console.log(e);
     }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use just - user.isEmailVerified, like so:

```
if(user.isEmailVerified){
  console.log("Email is verified");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much such a simple mistake.